# Install Visual SourceSafe

Tags: windows-10

I'm in the process of getting Visual SourceSafe installed on a few Window 10 computers.  I have installed on a few machines successfully but a few of the computers I'm receiving the following error " A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components.  Cancelling setup." I have attached the logs below.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: 
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: ========== Logging started ==========
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: =====================================
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({481CEF9F-033A-11D3-ACE2-00C04F8EEBA1})
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty(B51015E7-26A5-4c8f-B871-26ABA9BEFB65)
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: Command line parameters:
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: entering ISetupManager::RunIntro()
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: LoadSetupDatabase()
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::LoadSetupDatabase() - set InstalledFrom property to \\sditapsn01\SDITAP89\Applications\Licensed Software\VisualSourceSafe2005
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::LoadSuiteInfo() - we are in SP mode - no suiteinfo.dll is supported
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: Product Name:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe 2005 - English
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadSuiteRequirements
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : CheckSuiteBlocks
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadCommandLineMgr
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::LoadCommandLineMgr() completed
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadSetupLog
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:11] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::LoadSetupLog() completed
[05/24/19,13:34:11] UTILS::RunNGENAction: Started
[05/24/19,13:34:11] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue pause"
[05/24/19,13:34:12] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,13:34:12] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue pause"
[05/24/19,13:34:12] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,13:34:12] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadManagers
[05/24/19,13:34:12] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:12] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadUIManager()
[05/24/19,13:34:12] vs70uimgr: Entering InitializeModule() method.
[05/24/19,13:34:12] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::CopyTempFiles() - Installing setup files...
[05/24/19,13:34:12] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::InstallSetupFiles() starting
[05/24/19,13:34:12] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({39E467CB-8962-4AD8-99F9-864AFF183FD4})
[05/24/19,13:34:12] vs70uimgr: Entering ShowSmallProgress() method.
[05/24/19,13:34:13] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::CopyTempFiles() - Successfuly copied files to temp; rerunning Setup...
[05/24/19,13:34:14] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::CopyTempFiles() - Finished Rerunning Setup...
[05/24/19,13:34:14] Setup.exe: UnloadSuiteComponents()
[05/24/19,13:34:14] UTILS::RunNGENAction: Started
[05/24/19,13:34:14] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue continue"
[05/24/19,13:34:15] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,13:34:15] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue continue"
[05/24/19,13:34:15] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,13:34:15] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty(AA4EEF91-FB37-4135-9B73-484B75DDAA42)
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: 
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: ========== Logging started ==========
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: =====================================
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({481CEF9F-033A-11D3-ACE2-00C04F8EEBA1})
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty(B51015E7-26A5-4c8f-B871-26ABA9BEFB65)
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: Command line parameters: /CreatedTemp /NoExclude /InstalledFrom "\\sditapsn01\SDITAP89\Applications\Licensed Software\VisualSourceSafe2005"
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: entering ISetupManager::RunIntro()
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: LoadSetupDatabase()
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::LoadSetupDatabase() - set InstalledFrom property to C:\temp\SIT15659.tmp
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::LoadSuiteInfo() - we are in SP mode - no suiteinfo.dll is supported
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: Product Name:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe 2005 - English
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Initializing Progress Dialog Thread
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Waiting for Initialization event...
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: CCoreEngine-Proc() - Setting loading init Event...
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: CCoreEngine-Proc() - Finished Setting loading init Event
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: CCoreEngine-Proc() - Entering Main Message Loop...
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Initializing Progress Bar
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadSuiteRequirements
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : CheckSuiteBlocks
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadCommandLineMgr
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::LoadCommandLineMgr() completed
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadSetupLog
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({1B3F6DC3-205F-11D3-A824-00C04FB1799F})
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({383F0141-C682-4665-A69B-756E719C968D})
[05/24/19,13:34:25] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::LoadSetupLog() completed
[05/24/19,13:34:26] UTILS::RunNGENAction: Started
[05/24/19,13:34:26] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue pause"
[05/24/19,13:34:26] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,13:34:26] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue pause"
[05/24/19,13:34:27] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadManagers
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadDependencyMgr()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadCDInfoMgr()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadDiskInfoMgr()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadUIManager()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] vs70uimgr: Entering InitializeModule() method.
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadDatabaseValues
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:27] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({2C320A80-183E-4F7E-8832-66A0F5756221})
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({8297A38B-6431-4F1D-9F6E-C3D371CEA383})
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({B8A13F14-4BDE-4EC4-A53C-8E51FBB8261F})
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({AA62DF98-3F2C-11D3-887B-00C04F8ECDD6})
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({8297A38B-6431-4F1D-9F6E-C3D371CEA383})
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({E0875D42-A33D-4C64-81C9-167795F29CA4})
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:28] MSITOSIT: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CRootComponent::SetManager() - MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
[05/24/19,13:34:28] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:29] MSITOSIT: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : ERROR processed; exception was thrown for retail build
    Developer Comment:  MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
    Build Time:  Thu Dec 11 15:04:18 2003
    DWORD:  0
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({8297A38B-6431-4F1D-9F6E-C3D371CEA383})
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : ISetupModule::SetManager() failed in ISetupManager::LoadSetupObjectGuid() : vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CSetupManager::LoadSetupObjectname() - Failed in call to LoadSetupObjectGuid() for strName:  in file: vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : LoadComponent(), LoadSetupObjectName failure: vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : LoadComponent failed in ISetupManager::LoadComponentsFromDBObject(): vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CSetupManager::LoadDatabaseValues() - Failed in call to LoadComponentsFroMDBObjects()
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Failed to Load Database Values
[05/24/19,13:34:29] vs70uimgr: Entering DisplayMessage() method.
[05/24/19,13:34:29] Setup.exe: CCoreEngine-Proc() - Finished Main Message Loop
[05/24/19,13:34:29] vs70uimgr: DisplayMessage_START:A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup.
[05/24/19,13:34:31] vs70uimgr: DisplayMessage_END:A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup.
[05/24/19,13:34:31] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,13:34:31] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CSetupManager::RunLoadSetup() - Failed to Run the Intro
[05/24/19,13:34:31] Setup.exe: UnloadSuiteComponents()
[05/24/19,13:34:31] UTILS::RunNGENAction: Started
[05/24/19,13:34:31] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue continue"
[05/24/19,13:34:32] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,13:34:32] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue continue"
[05/24/19,13:34:32] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,13:34:32] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty(AA4EEF91-FB37-4135-9B73-484B75DDAA42)
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: 
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: ========== Logging started ==========
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: =====================================
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({481CEF9F-033A-11D3-ACE2-00C04F8EEBA1})
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty(B51015E7-26A5-4c8f-B871-26ABA9BEFB65)
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: Command line parameters:
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: entering ISetupManager::RunIntro()
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: LoadSetupDatabase()
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::LoadSetupDatabase() - set InstalledFrom property to \\sditapsn01\SDITAP89\Applications\Licensed Software\VisualSourceSafe2005
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::LoadSuiteInfo() - we are in SP mode - no suiteinfo.dll is supported
[05/24/19,14:04:12] Setup.exe: Product Name:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe 2005 - English
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadSuiteRequirements
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : CheckSuiteBlocks
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadCommandLineMgr
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::LoadCommandLineMgr() completed
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadSetupLog
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:13] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::LoadSetupLog() completed
[05/24/19,14:04:13] UTILS::RunNGENAction: Started
[05/24/19,14:04:13] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue pause"
[05/24/19,14:04:13] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,14:04:13] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue pause"
[05/24/19,14:04:14] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,14:04:14] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadManagers
[05/24/19,14:04:14] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:14] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadUIManager()
[05/24/19,14:04:14] vs70uimgr: Entering InitializeModule() method.
[05/24/19,14:04:14] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::CopyTempFiles() - Installing setup files...
[05/24/19,14:04:14] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::InstallSetupFiles() starting
[05/24/19,14:04:14] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({39E467CB-8962-4AD8-99F9-864AFF183FD4})
[05/24/19,14:04:14] vs70uimgr: Entering ShowSmallProgress() method.
[05/24/19,14:04:15] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::CopyTempFiles() - Successfuly copied files to temp; rerunning Setup...
[05/24/19,14:04:16] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::CopyTempFiles() - Finished Rerunning Setup...
[05/24/19,14:04:16] Setup.exe: UnloadSuiteComponents()
[05/24/19,14:04:16] UTILS::RunNGENAction: Started
[05/24/19,14:04:16] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue continue"
[05/24/19,14:04:17] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,14:04:17] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue continue"
[05/24/19,14:04:17] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,14:04:17] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty(AA4EEF91-FB37-4135-9B73-484B75DDAA42)
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: 
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: ========== Logging started ==========
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: =====================================
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({481CEF9F-033A-11D3-ACE2-00C04F8EEBA1})
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty(B51015E7-26A5-4c8f-B871-26ABA9BEFB65)
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: Command line parameters: /CreatedTemp /NoExclude /InstalledFrom "\\sditapsn01\SDITAP89\Applications\Licensed Software\VisualSourceSafe2005"
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: entering ISetupManager::RunIntro()
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: LoadSetupDatabase()
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::LoadSetupDatabase() - set InstalledFrom property to C:\temp\SIT21544.tmp
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::LoadSuiteInfo() - we are in SP mode - no suiteinfo.dll is supported
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: Product Name:Microsoft Visual SourceSafe 2005 - English
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Initializing Progress Dialog Thread
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Waiting for Initialization event...
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: CCoreEngine-Proc() - Setting loading init Event...
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Finished Waiting for Initialization event
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: CCoreEngine-Proc() - Entering Main Message Loop...
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Initializing Progress Bar
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadSuiteRequirements
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : CheckSuiteBlocks
[05/24/19,14:04:27] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadCommandLineMgr
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::LoadCommandLineMgr() completed
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadSetupLog
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({1B3F6DC3-205F-11D3-A824-00C04FB1799F})
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({383F0141-C682-4665-A69B-756E719C968D})
[05/24/19,14:04:28] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::LoadSetupLog() completed
[05/24/19,14:04:28] UTILS::RunNGENAction: Started
[05/24/19,14:04:28] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue pause"
[05/24/19,14:04:28] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,14:04:28] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue pause"
[05/24/19,14:04:29] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadManagers
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadDependencyMgr()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadCDInfoMgr()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadDiskInfoMgr()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: inside ISetupManager::LoadUIManager()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] vs70uimgr: Entering InitializeModule() method.
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: ISetupManager::RunIntro() : LoadDatabaseValues
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:29] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({2C320A80-183E-4F7E-8832-66A0F5756221})
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({8297A38B-6431-4F1D-9F6E-C3D371CEA383})
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({B8A13F14-4BDE-4EC4-A53C-8E51FBB8261F})
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({AA62DF98-3F2C-11D3-887B-00C04F8ECDD6})
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({8297A38B-6431-4F1D-9F6E-C3D371CEA383})
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({E0875D42-A33D-4C64-81C9-167795F29CA4})
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:30] MSITOSIT: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CRootComponent::SetManager() - MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
[05/24/19,14:04:30] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:31] MSITOSIT: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : ERROR processed; exception was thrown for retail build
    Developer Comment:  MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
    Build Time:  Thu Dec 11 15:04:18 2003
    DWORD:  0
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: GetCustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: get_CustomProperties()
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty({8297A38B-6431-4F1D-9F6E-C3D371CEA383})
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: MoveLoadProgress()
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : ISetupModule::SetManager() failed in ISetupManager::LoadSetupObjectGuid() : vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CSetupManager::LoadSetupObjectname() - Failed in call to LoadSetupObjectGuid() for strName:  in file: vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : LoadComponent(), LoadSetupObjectName failure: vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : LoadComponent failed in ISetupManager::LoadComponentsFromDBObject(): vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CSetupManager::LoadDatabaseValues() - Failed in call to LoadComponentsFroMDBObjects()
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Failed to Load Database Values
[05/24/19,14:04:31] vs70uimgr: Entering DisplayMessage() method.
[05/24/19,14:04:31] vs70uimgr: DisplayMessage_START:A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup.
[05/24/19,14:04:31] Setup.exe: CCoreEngine-Proc() - Finished Main Message Loop
[05/24/19,14:25:35] vs70uimgr: DisplayMessage_END:A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup.
[05/24/19,14:25:35] Setup.exe: AddGlobalCustomProperty
[05/24/19,14:25:35] setup.exe: ***ERRORLOG EVENT*** : CSetupManager::RunLoadSetup() - Failed to Run the Intro
[05/24/19,14:25:35] Setup.exe: UnloadSuiteComponents()
[05/24/19,14:25:35] UTILS::RunNGENAction: Started
[05/24/19,14:25:35] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue continue"
[05/24/19,14:25:36] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,14:25:36] UTILS::RunNGENAction: starting "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ngen.exe queue continue"
[05/24/19,14:25:36] UTILS::RunNGENAction: ngen.exe returned 0
[05/24/19,14:25:36] Setup.exe: GetGlobalCustomProperty(AA4EEF91-FB37-4135-9B73-484B75DDAA42)


[05/24/19,13:34:28] MSITOSIT: [2] CRootComponent::SetManager() - MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
[05/24/19,13:34:29] MSITOSIT: [2] ERROR processed; exception was thrown for retail build
    Developer Comment:  MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
    Build Time:  Thu Dec 11 15:04:18 2003
    DWORD:  0
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: [2] ISetupModule::SetManager() failed in ISetupManager::LoadSetupObjectGuid() : vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadSetupObjectname() - Failed in call to LoadSetupObjectGuid() for strName:  in file: vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent(), LoadSetupObjectName failure: vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent failed in ISetupManager::LoadComponentsFromDBObject(): vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadDatabaseValues() - Failed in call to LoadComponentsFroMDBObjects()
[05/24/19,13:34:29] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Failed to Load Database Values
[05/24/19,13:34:31] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunLoadSetup() - Failed to Run the Intro
[05/24/19,14:04:30] MSITOSIT: [2] CRootComponent::SetManager() - MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
[05/24/19,14:04:30] MSITOSIT: [2] ERROR processed; exception was thrown for retail build
    Developer Comment:  MsiGetActiveDatabase returned an invalid handle
    Build Time:  Thu Dec 11 15:04:18 2003
    DWORD:  0
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: [2] ISetupModule::SetManager() failed in ISetupManager::LoadSetupObjectGuid() : vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadSetupObjectname() - Failed in call to LoadSetupObjectGuid() for strName:  in file: vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent(), LoadSetupObjectName failure: vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: [0] LoadComponent failed in ISetupManager::LoadComponentsFromDBObject(): vs_setup.dll
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::LoadDatabaseValues() - Failed in call to LoadComponentsFroMDBObjects()
[05/24/19,14:04:31] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunIntro() - Failed to Load Database Values
[05/24/19,14:25:35] setup.exe: [2] CSetupManager::RunLoadSetup() - Failed to Run the Intro
```

Comment: Tried setting the TEMP and TMP variables to C:\TEMP and still go the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This product hasn't been used since 2005 and was never good to begin with.
This specific error was a known bug for VisualStudio 2005 setup (which this was a part of).

I would *suggest* using ***ANYTHING*** else but VSS.  Microsoft wouldn't even use it back in the day...  but I am not here to judge.. just help you.

To get you around the problem, try this:

**Solution**:  Change USER variables of both TEMP and TMP to point to something valid like C:\TEMP.  C:\TEMP must exist and be read/write by ALL users.

You ***should be able*** to open a command prompt (as Administrator) and set the TEMP and TMP variables there. After that, ***be sure*** to use that same cmd.exe instance to launch setup.

You might need to actually set the user environment variables in windows temporarily if the MSI installer is somehow reading them directly (but I doubt it).

Comment: Agreed.  This an old, outdated, discontinued product.  There are plenty of free (and paid) modern, supported, far more capable source control products out there.